# Values From Button to Textbox

Tags: c#

i Have one textbox.text on windows form and two buttons. i want that if i press A button A is shown in textbox.text and when press B button B shown in textbox.text please help me?
i am using C# in Visual Studio

```
textBox1.Text = button1.Text;
textBox2.Text = button2.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the click handler in button1:

```
textBox1.Text = button1.Text;
```

And in the button2:

```
textBox2.Text = button2.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

`==` is a [boolean comparison operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) which for `a == b` means **is a the same as b**.
What you are looking for is the `=` [assignment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) which for `a = b` means **assign a the value of b**. Change your code to be:

```
textBox1.Text = button1.Content;  //button1.Text if ASP.NET vs. WPF.
//or
textBox1.Text = button2.Content;
```

If you want to do the assignment based on a button click, you need to set up an event handler for the button click event and then register the handler with an instance of the button. I assume you are using XAML since you indicated Windows Forms.

In the XAML:

```
<Button Name="buttonA" Click="buttonA_OnClick">A</Button>
<Button Name="buttonB" Click="buttonB_OnClick">B</Button>
<TextBox Name="text1" />
```

And in your code behind for the XAML:

```
void buttonA_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    text1.Text = buttonA.Content;
}

void buttonB_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    text1.Text = buttonB.Content;
}
```

Comment: one More that If i want that when i Press button1 then TextBox.Text Show A, and when i press button2 then TextBox.Text Shown both Values A and B Together.

Answer (score 1):

Use The Click Event Handlers of both the button to set the text of the text box.

On Click event of First button
Set textbox1.Text= button1.Text

On Click event of Second button
Set textbox1.Text= button2.Text

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void zero_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textbox.Text += "0";

        }
```

Comment: Hey there! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.